# Unable to confirm installation on program from unknown source

Tags: unknown-sources

I have a few programs I want to install that come from "[Unknown sources](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-manually-install-side-load-apps-on-your-android-device/)" (The latest [Humble Bundle](http://humblebundle.com) to be precise).

When trying to install the application, I get the normal "Do you want to install this application?" followed by the list of permissions required.

At the bottom, I can either "Cancel" the install, or proceed by pressing "Install".

Unfortunately, in my case, the "Install" "button", is not a button at all. It's a completely inactive text, and no matter if I tap it multiple times in different locations or long press it, it reacts in any way at all. Cancel works fine.

I've tried disabling the setting allowing installation from unknown sources and re-enabling it, and I've tried restarting the phone. Neither helped.

I've tried several of the humble bundle applications, and the issue is the same with all of them. Since the confirmation dialogue is a part of Android, I assume the issue is unrelated to Humble Bundle.

[image: Android APK confirmation dialog]

Comment: what is the application you are trying to install?!

Comment: I had tried "Aaaaaaaaaa!", "Anomoly 2". Trying "McPixel", which is from an earlier bundle, that worked! I'll investigate further.

Comment: Since you're downloading those apps from sources different than Google Play, the validation of compatibility with your device may not be taking place (BTW, what brand and model is your device?). If the apps you try to install are not compatible with your device, Android will not let you to install them.

Comment: I'm using a nexus 5. Same issue again, now with IITC. http://iitc.jonatkins.com/?page=mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by [Twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux&hl=en), which had an option that can fix the install issue.

With "Auto-pause in specified apps" ticket, and "APK Installer (button fix)", the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks! I only installed twilight recently and had no idea it would mess things like this.

Comment: Me neither, but as you can see from when I asked the question, I've used it for a long time, and this is the only issue I've ever noticed with it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fnally solved after i downloaded an app permission manager, and disabled the draw-over permission in an app called solver for pad (no shame :) ).

Comment: Please link the app from play store